# C++0x array to iterator without using begin/end

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, c++03

How do I convert a C++ array of pairs to an iterator, without using `std::begin()` and `std::end()`?

Context:
I'm trying to sort an array of pairs using the first element (can be assumed to be unique). Following the instructions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-vector-of-pairs-in-c-set-1-sort-by-first-and-second/), where a vector is used:

```
int main()
{
vector<pair <int,int>> vect;

int arr[] = {10, 20, 5, 40 };
int arr1[] = {30, 60, 20, 50};

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    vect.push_back(make_pair(arr[i],arr1[i]));

sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());
return 0;
}
```

I know the size of the array in advance though, and so (apart from calling a `resize` on `vect`) I wanted to do something along the lines of:

```
int main()
{
auto *p_arr = (pair<int, int>*) malloc(4 * sizeof(pair<int, int>));

int arr[] = {10, 20, 5, 40 };
int arr1[] = {30, 60, 20, 50};

for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    p_arr[i] = make_pair(arr[i],arr1[i]);

sort(begin(p_arr), end(p_arr));
return 0;
}
```

But, C++0x doesn't have `begin()` and `end()`. Also, my actual code has this defined within a function, with the size of the array supplied externally, so I can't do `pair <int, int>[4] vect;` as well, not sure whether that's relevant.

Hence my question. Is there an alternative to `begin()` and `end()`, or should I stick to using `vector` for my problem?

Edit: Changed variable name from `vect` to `p_arr` in second code sample for clarity.

Comment: `sort(vect, vect + 4)`. Though it's not clear what you hope to gain by allocating memory manually (which you, by the way, leak) as opposed to having `std::vector` allocate that same memory for you.

Comment: Just use the vector.  instead of calling `resize` though call `reserve`.  This will allocate the memory but not construct any elements so it will be faster.

Comment: Oh, and `end(vect)` won't in fact work (in the second example), since `vect` doesn't know its size. `std::end()` works on a proper array (among other things), not on a pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, of course, `std::end` will work on vector.

Comment: @SergeyA I meant `vect` as used in the second example (clarified the comment), where, despite the misleading name, it's a plain pointer.

Comment: Thanks guys! It's partly because this is part of a homework assignment, so I'm not sure whether we're even allowed to use vectors, and also because I have this (mis)conception that manually allocating memory will make the whole thing more efficient. C++ is new to me. Give me a couple of minutes to try out the suggestion :)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it feels like OP's choice of words and variable names is really unfortunate.

Comment: Unless you have very specific reasons to use malloc and raw pointers, even if you get it to work I think you're better off using a vector.  Raw pointers definitely have a place, but heuristically, one should avoid them until proven necessary.

Comment: @Melvin - yes, you do have a significant misconception.   Manually allocating memory does not, in itself, make your program more efficient.   Given a choice between a professionally crafted container and allocators in your compiler's standard library, and a simple minded "doing it by hand makes it more efficient", I'll bet on the standard containers being more efficient - by almost any measure of efficiency.    And, of course, it is easier to get code working correctly with a standard container (properly deallocating memory, etc) than it is when doing things manually.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik, your solution works! Sorry for the confusing variable naming, should have checked before copy-pasted it here.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've not seen `reserve` before actually, thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @SergeyA Sorry for the naming, should have checked before. I believe you posted an answer previously which I haven't seen, but it appears to be gone now. Thanks for your help and effort!

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis That's true, the assignment code we're given has `malloc` everywhere, so I thought the tutor really liked them. I posted my previous comment just right before yours though, so you probably hasn't seen it. I agree with your point.

Comment: @Peter I agree, especially given my inadvertent leak, which I didn't actually realise before, heh.

Comment: *"the assignment code we're given has malloc everywhere, so I thought the tutor really liked them"* Run away as fast as you can. Leave [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) as a clue...

Answer (score 0):

For an array `a` of type `T[N]`, you can easily get the "begin" and "end" as `a` and `a+N` respectively, which you will be able to substitute without issues.

That said, backporting `begin` and `end` from C++11 to C++03 is very easy to do. I've done it myself using the [information about the functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) in cppreference as a guide.